# How can I use a parameter to change HTML text?

Tags: javascript, html, function, innerhtml

I'm using an API, and am trying to access the value of product.shoeName to change text on my HTML page. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" 
            src="shoepoo.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      
        <div>
            <p id="text" style="color:purple; 
                font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;">
            </p>
            <script type="text/javascript"> shoeName(); </script>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
const SneaksAPI = require('sneaks-api');
const sneaks = new SneaksAPI();

//getProducts(keyword, limit, callback) takes in a keyword and limit and returns a product array 
function shoeName(){
sneaks.getProducts("Jumbo Blazer", 1, function(err, products){
    
    products.forEach(
        function names (product) {
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = product.shoeName;
    })
    
});
};
```

Basically, I want product.shoeName to be shown as text, but nothing is showing up. How can I fix this? I understand it's a local function which is probably stopping the data from being shown (or something like that), but how can I work around this?

Comment: Is your `sneaks` function in node? Are you using something like require.js? I'm not really sure I understand how you're getting data from this api, but there's a lot to say about this code...

Comment: are you calling the function  shoeName()

Comment: The function is in node, and i'm just trying to get the data to be put into an HTML page. When i console.log(product.shoeName), the name prints successfully, but when trying to put it on a page, it remains blank.

Answer (score 0):

Made below changes in `shoepoo.js`

```
products.forEach((product)=> {
     document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = product.shoeName;
});
```

But you need to create dynamic HTML components if there is multiple data in `products`. Otherwise, it set the last `shoeName` in the paragraph component.

Comment: That change did not change any output on the html page. It's still coming up blank

Comment: Oops, Not `innerHTML` use `innerText`.